# How to resolve merging conflicts in Mercurial (v1.0.2)?

Tags: mercurial, merge, dvcs, conflict

I have a merging conflict, using Mercurial 1.0.2:

```
merging test.h
warning: conflicts during merge.
merging test.h failed!
6 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 1 files unresolved
There are unresolved merges, you can redo the full merge using:
  hg update -C 19
  hg merge 18
```

I can't figure out how to resolve this. Google search results instruct to use:

```
hg resolve
```

but for some reason my Mercurial (v1.0.2) doesn't have a resolve command:

```
hg: unknown command 'resolve'
```

How can I resolve this conflict?

Comment: I think you have to mark a different answer as the correct one..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Valid for hg < v1.1 only**

There is no need to call any `hg` commands. Unlike `svn`, Mercurial does not track conflicted files. If you call `hg status`, you'll see that the file is simply marked as modified.

Just fix the file by hand and commit.

Comment: So it looks like Mercurial moved my local copy to test.h.orig and test.h is now from the other head... is there any way to prevent creation of the .orig file so it doesn't get added accidentally?

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible, but you can add *.orig to your .hgignore file.

Comment: If you simply edit the file and then commit, its possible that it wont be recognized as a merge of the two branches, merely a new commit on your working one.

I think you have to fix the file by hand and then do **hg resolve -m test.h** to mark the file as merged.

Comment: The second parent is automatically added to the working directory even when 'hg merge' fails to resolve some conflicted files.

Comment: *Note* This answer is for hg pre 1.1.

Comment: @lajos could you accept the (now) correct answer below, please?

Answer (score 80):

*To highlight an answer in a comment for Hg 1.1+:*

For **Hg 1.1+** fix the file by hand and then do

```
hg resolve -m test.h
```

to mark the file as merged.

Comment: same question. What to do with .orig files then?

Comment: here is a nice quick way to do this *hg st -un | grep orig | xargs rm*

Comment: Dori, I would add a $ to the end of that grep, just so you don't accidentally catch something you didn't mean to.

Answer (score 10):

Tracking conflicts was introduced in [Mercurial 1.1](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/WhatsNew#Version_1.1_-_2008-12-2), which is a newer version that you are using (you should really upgrade, Mercurial 1.1. was released in December 2008). 
In that version you gained the `resolve` command which works similarly to `svn resolve`.

As I remember it, Mercurial would leave merge markers (the `<<<<` and `>>>>` lines) in your file when there is a conflict, unless you have configured a [merge tool](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MergeToolConfiguration). This also applies to newer versions -- I have no merge tool configured and get the merge markers when conflicts occur. I can then manually fix the file and mark it resolved with `hg resolve`.